# <form:select> does not comes selected

Tags: java, spring-mvc, selected

My page has some combos  but I don't know why one of this combos doesn't comes selected on edit mode.

If i put to show the value and the id of the fiel with  the values appears ok, because of this there's no reason to my combo doesn't comes selected.

Here is my combo with problem:

```
<form:select required="true" path="orcamento.area">
<form:option value="" label="--- Selecione ---" />  
<form:options items="${listaArea}" itemLabel="descricao" itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

If if put:
     
     
Everything appears correctly

My other combos like the one below correctly displays the selected data:

```
<form:select required="true" path="orcamento.representante" id="selectRepresentante"     name="representante">
<form:option value="" label="--- Selecione ---" />
<form:options items="${listaFuncionario}" itemLabel="nome" itemValue="id" />
```

Comment: What do you mean with *one of this combos doesn't comes selected on edit mode*?

Comment: @user2403973 I didn't understood the way you put your question.. plz be more specific and clear..

Comment: Sorry, I will try to be more clear. There are some records being displayed on the screen (table), if I click a particular registered to edit it the combo (form:select) should come with its selected value. The step of clicking a record to edit your information is what I called "edit mode"